# HTML file saved from TextEdit shown as source code in the browser

Tags: macos, textedit

For some reason, when I type HTML into TextEdit and save it as an HTML document, and I load it, I see all the text, unformatted, including the tags. How would I fix this?

Comment: "load it" into what? Safari?

Comment: Could you post the code you are using?

Comment: Firefox. And I's just <html> <body> Test </body </html>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to click "Make Plain Text" in the "Format" menu of TextEdit and then save the file with the extension ".html"

Comment: Now when I try to open it in text edit, it appears all black. I can't edit it after saving.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I'm guessing that TextEdit is trying to edit the html in WYSIWYG mode ("rich text mode"). There may be some way to force it to go one way or the other, but I'm not sure how. Personally, I'd recommend using something like TextWrangler.

Answer (score -1):

Try opening it with safari, or your current web browser.   This can probally be done by clicking file>open (within the browser).

Here is a list of well known HTML editors designed specifically for macs. http://webdesign.about.com/od/macintoshhtmleditors/tp/macintosh-text-editors.htm has a list of software that is known for working great with

Comment: I'd really like to just edit this in textedit and open it in firefox. Even opening it from within firefox won't work.

Comment: Dreamweaver, Komodo Edit, CS5, Aptana Studio, NetBeans, Bluefish, Eclipse, (skEdit) and Seamonkey - all hand-crafted for OS X and great replacements for someone using TextEdit to edit HTML.